# How can I create functions in jQuery and call it on event and pass variable to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, function

```
$(".addcart").click(function(){

   $("input[name='items']:checked").each(function() {
       //doing something
   });

});
```

I'm trying to create a common class onclick of which I'm doing something. Is there a way I can make "items" a variable, I mean Can I pass checkbox name to this event.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do? Something like the below? $(".addcart").click(function(){ var cbxName = 'items'; $("input[name='" + cbxName + "']:checked").each(function() { //doing something }); });

Comment: can you add more detail?... it's a little bit blur..

Comment: The event is the function you pass to `click`, you aren't wanting to pass the variable to that, you want to pass it to the function you call with `each`. I suggest you edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: I'm sorry guys I think my question was not very correct. It should be "How can I create functions in jQuery and call it on event and pass variable to it"

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works out:

```
$("input[name='items']:checked").each(function() {
  alert(this.attr("name"));
});
```

I think I've used like this somewhere.

[EDIT]
The thing with this is that jQuery passes the current item to the foreach as the context of the variable.

Comment: you probably mean `this.name` and not `this.attr("name")` or if so wrap it with jQuery like this, `$(this).attr("name")`

Comment: sorry! youre right! is like that, the code is $(this).attr("name"), not very sure about using this.name instead.

Comment: This code is somewhat silly. You're iterating over all `input` items with the name `items` and checking for what the name is..... Hint: `items`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) instead of click

```
$(".addcart").bind("click", {name: "items"}, function(event){
   $("input[name='" + event.data.name + "']:checked").each(function() {
       //doing something
   });
});
```

**edit:**

> "How can I create functions in jQuery
>   and call it on event and pass variable
>   to it"

That will still be the same procedure. Use `bind` to attach an event handler, pass it an object with the needed stuff for your function. In your event handler call your function and pass it the object from event.data

```
$(".addcart").bind("click", {foo: "hello world"}, function(event) {
   DoSomethingOnClick(event.data);
});

function DoSomethingOnClick(obj) {
   obj = obj || {};
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty('foo'))
      alert(obj["foo"]);
   else
      alert("no foo here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that all checked items will have a name of `items`, so that's not very interesting, but maybe you want to retrieve the `value` of each of the `items`:

```
$(".addcart").click(function(){

   $("input[name='items']:checked").each(function() {

         // To access an attribute of this item use the form $(this).attr(...)
       alert( this.value );

   });

});
```

The above uses `this` to access the element being iterated over. Take a look at **[the properties of a DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element)** to see what properties of `this` you can access.

You can create a jQuery object out of `this` using the form `$(this)` then you can use **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to access the attributes of `this`. For example to get the class/es of `this` you can use either `this.className` or `$(this).attr("class")`.

It is faster to directly access the DOM element's properties. But for some more complex manipulations it is good to know that `$(this)` is also available.

Comment: Use `this.value` and `this.whatever-property-you-have-attached-to-the-DOM-element` (kind of tired of saying this)

Comment: @Yi Jiang - The rude parenthetical expression is completely unnecessary.